# jQuery ajax() using success, error and complete vs .done(), .fail() and always()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

**The questions**:

1. Should we change our coding as suggested below?
2. Is there a difference between `.done()` & `success:`, `.fail()` & `error:` and `.always()` & `complete:`?

**The preamble**:

I was putting together a jQuery.ajax call, which I have done successfully in the past too. Something like this:

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: someUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: someData,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) { someSuccessFunction(data); },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { someErrorFunction(); }
    });
```

While taking a quick look at some documentation, I came across a reference stating that The success, error and complete callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

We should therefore start coding something like this instead:

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
    .done(function (data) { someSuccessFunction(data); })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { someErrorFunction(); })
    .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: i prefer the second method... where the promise returned by ajax is used

Comment: The callbacks aren't deprecated. The related methods on the jqxhr object are.

Comment: I agree with Arun, also I think thats personally easier to read

Comment: I'm not looking for comments and statements about preference, but would like to understand the differences, if there are any.

Comment: To those who don't know what jqxhr objects are, what Crazy Train means by "The callbacks aren't deprecated. The related methods on the jqxhr object are." is that `.done()` replaces `.success()`, `.fail()` replaces `.error()`, and `.always()` replaces `.complete()`.

The `.success()`, `.error()`, and `.complete()` **methods** are different from the `success`, `error`, and `complete` **options** for the `.ajax()` method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well there is no advantage of doing that in that particular situation.

The point of the `.done()` `.fail()` `.always()` methods is that you can

1. Attach multiple handlers
2. Do so anywhere and not just when calling `$.ajax`

If you are at the `$.ajax` call site only attaching single handlers then those advantages don't really come into play.

So you can return the promise and others may attach their own handlers.

Example is refreshing plugins after ajax request:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(opt, origOpt, jqxhr) {
    jqxhr.always(function() {
        $("[data-plugin]").plugin();
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI - According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as of jQuery 1.5 the `complete`, `error` and `success` settings will accept an array of callback functions, so you can attach multiple handlers.

Comment: for #2: where else would these methods be used besides when calling `$.ajax()`? Do these methods only work on jqxhr receivers?