# Get Http Status Code from an ajax response with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-codes

In my current spring project, when I submit a form to server, the response is handled by this method:

```
    $('form.form').each(function () {
        var form = this;
        $(form).ajaxForm(function (data) {
            form.reset();
            $(".alert-info").find("#alert").html(data);
            $(".alert-info").show();
        });
    });
```

In my controller, the submission is handled by a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value="icone", required=false) MultipartFile icone, @RequestParam(value="screenshot", required=false) MultipartFile screenshot[]) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
    serv.cadastra(object);
    serv.upload_picture(object, file, "picture");
    serv.upload_picture(object, icone, "icone");
}
```

Error responses from the methods from the controller are handled by this ControllerAdvice class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@PropertySource({"classpath:error.properties"})
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
        // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus rethrow it and let
        // the framework handle it - like the OrderNotFoundException example
        // at the start of this post.
        // AnnotationUtils is a Spring Framework utility class.
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null)
            throw e;
        // Otherwise setup and send the user to a default error-view.
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.addObject("msg", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        mav.setViewName("erro");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

I am looking for a way to read the http status code from response (which can be 1xx, 2xx, 3xx, 4xx or 5xx) in my jquery code, and display a related message according to this code.

In the network monitor from browser, I can see a successful response already have the code HTTP 201 as implemented in the method; when an error occurs, the response should have a code 4xx or 5xx, depending from exception triggered.

In this way, I wonder if anyone can give a hint of how modify my jquery code and my COntrollerAdvice to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). If so, the third parameter to the callback function is the `xhr` object, and you can get the HTTP status like this:

```
$(form).ajaxForm(function (data, statusText, xhr) {
    alert(xhr.status);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tdmoc9s/)

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post", url: "/SomeController/SomeAction",
    success: function (data, text) {
        //...
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

e.g.

```
error: function(xhr,err){
    alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
}
```

xhr is short for XmlHttpRequest.

readyState: the values are 1:loading, 2:loaded, 3:interactive, 4:complete

status: the HTTP status number, like 404 not found, 500 internal server error, 200: ok (warning: special IE problem value: 0 cancelled)

responseText: the response from the server - this could be your custom status text (make sure the status code is not 200 OK)

If you want to check the status even on success, use always:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
.done(function (data) { alert(data); })
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { someErrorFunction(); })
.always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Also, see this post on success-error-complete vs. done-fail-always
[jQuery ajax() using success, error and complete vs .done(), .fail() and always()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264237/jquery-ajax-using-success-error-and-complete-vs-done-fail-and-always)

If you want to setup a global error handling on the page, use ajaxSetup:
http://www.unseenrevolution.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function/

Answer (score 2):

To get headers and status in response:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data
}).done(function(rs, textStatus, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('X-CUSTOM-HEADER'));
    console.log(xhr.status);
});
```

see also: [Using getResponseHeader with jQuery’s ajax method](http://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2014/08/using-getresponseheader-with-jquerys-ajax-method/)