# How do I wait for an action to finish before showing the next alert using sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert, sweetalert2

So I have an ASP.NET MVC Core project and when I click a button I want to display an alert using  sweetalert2.

The button looks like this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doFunction(@(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(number))); ">Click</a>
```

And the JavaScript looks like this

```
function doFunction(model) {
        Swal.queue([{
            title: 'TestData',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK',
            text: 'TestData',
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            preConfirm: () => {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Tester", "Home")',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: { data: "yourdata" },
                        dataType: "json",
                        //success: function(recData) { alert('Success'); },
                        //error: function() { alert('A error'); }
                }).then(Swal.insertQueueStep("Woo", "Woo"))
                    .catch(() => {
                        Swal.insertQueueStep({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: 'Something went wrong'
                        })
                    });
            }
        }])
    }
```

And here is the Action

```
public IActionResult Tester()
        {

            using (var context = new DbContext(_context))
            {
                var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == "TheUser");
                return new JsonResult(user.UserName);
            }
        }
```

And right now it displays an alert, and when I click "OK" it shows the next alert but no loading window inbetween.

How do I properly call an action that's inside a controller and display a loading alert while it waits for the action to finish, followed by a finished alert.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`DONE, Fail option in ajax`, move it under there..](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   context: document.body
 }).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
 });
```

---

```
   $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
         url: '@Url.Action("Tester", "Home")',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: { data: "yourdata" },
         // dataType: "json", // comment this out

    // blah blah... and then the done option... below
    
    done: function(data){ 
        if (doSomeValidcheck(data)){
                Swal.insertQueueStep("Woo", "Woo"))
                // blah blah ...
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Looks like we need to remove the [datatype json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822866/6085193)

---

Update:

Move the done to the *end of the Ajax call* like so...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url : postUrl,
    data: data
}).done(function()  {
    alert("Success.");
})
```

Comment: Hm, it seems as if the done function never fires