# jQuery .done not firing on a $.post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Firstly, here's my example code:

```
$.post( "test.php", { testdata : "signal" },
            function( data ) { alert( "Nested function" )})
 .done( function () { alert( "Done function" )});
```

I'm trying to get `.done` to accomplish some stuff for me, it doesn't matter what. It won't fire, regardless of whether or not I nest a function directly in the `$.post` parameters. Checking the console on Chrome shows that it's throwing an error of `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Playing around with lines and the error report shows me that it's definitely the `.done` that's throwing the error, and that simply moving the `.done` to directly after `$.post`'s close paren isn't effective.

There is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744066/jquery-ajax-done-function-not-firing) that I saw, but it was for $.ajax, and I've attempted to implement the chaining they suggest, as above, to no effect. What am I missing?

**EDIT: jQuery version is 1.4.4, the .post successfully returns data, and .always also fails.**

Comment: Are you inside a document ready function and sure that the jQuery library has loaded successfully?  What version of jQuery are you using?  Is the post maybe failing and you're getting into the fail callback?  Can you log something in the always callback?

Comment: Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/2LgMg/

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.4.4. The post succeeds and returns data. `.always` also refuses to fire.

Comment: @EmmettR. [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) and [related methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) were added with jQuery 1.5. You'll need to upgrade to use `.done()`, `.always()`, etc.

Comment: Try property `success` in version 1.4.4 like this `$.post("test.php", { testdata: "signal", success: function(data) {}});`

Comment: .always is called 'always'. If the ajax call fails and if it succeeded

Comment: Hmm... I have to keep version 1.4.4 for compatibility. Would it be excessive to install both an updated and an outdated version on my server, or would that cause collisions?

Comment: @EmmettR. It is possible. See [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) Note: It will depend on plugins using [the suggested closures](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope).

Comment: @algorhythm On on v1.5 and above. Before 1.5 you'll need to use the `complete` callback as deferreds were not yet supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after investigation, and thanks to the comments of Jonathan Lonowski, algorhythm and War10ck, I've discovered the solution.

The version of jQuery I was running, 1.4.4, does not support the .done, .fail, .always, or .complete* methods. To fire an event after a success, I need to follow the inline format of:

`$.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`

...inserting the function that would normally go into `.done`, after the url. This is what I was doing with the nested function in my original example, just requiring me to remove the .done function.

Thanks all.

**.complete is also deprecated in more recent builds of jQuery. Don't ever use it.*

Answer (score 0):

Use `.complete` instead:

```
$.post("test.php", { testdata : "signal" }, function () { 
        alert("Nested function"); })
    .complete(function () { alert("Done function"); });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X45Vq/)

Comment: Note: `jqXHR.complete()` was introduced in 1.5 and [deprecated with 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Comment: It's also not available in 1.4.4, as I tested it.

Comment: @EmmettR. Are you sure? Check [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js) and do a find (CTRL + F) for "ajaxComplete". It returns two event listings...

Comment: @War10ck Though, that's not what this answer is referring to. `jqXHR.complete()` was a short-lived (1.5.x - 1.7.x) alias of `.always()` for `jqXHR` objects.